# How can I limit the maximum number of threads when using Task.Run()?

Tags: c#, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, threadpool

I want to limit the maximum number of threads. How can I do it? I know I could use something like `SetMaximum`...if I were using the `ThreadPool`.

```cs
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Task.Run(Work);
    }
}

async Task Work()
{
    // some time-consuming job
}
```

Comment: `while (true)` will limit the number of `Task`s to as many as can run before some OS resource or another is exhausted.  Do you want to limit the number of `Task`s that are started?  `for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)` would do that.  Or do you want to limit the number of `Task`s running concurrently?  To the number of cores, or what?  (Or was that tag supposed to be [tag:.net-core]?)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a SemaphoreSlim to limit the number of concurrent threads. For example to limit the execution to 3 threads at a time:

```
async Task  Main()
{
    SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(3); // Limit to 3 threads
    while (true)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync(); // Wait when more than 3 threads are running
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Work();
            semaphore.Release(); // Work is done, signal to semaphore that more work is possible
        });
    }

}

void Work()
{
    Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

Semaphores can be used to limit the consumption of many types of resources, but in this example the resource is a thread from the thread pool.